# Fitting the Muon Rate Equation for the Muon intensity experiment

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

This is regarding the standard muon intensity experiment where we use three scintillation detectors to measure the intensity of muons with respect to the zenith. The device measures the intensity over an angle and the problem boils down to fitting an equation of the form

$$ y = f(\phi,A,n) = \int_{\phi- \alpha}^{\phi+ \alpha}A\cos^n(\theta)d\theta .$$

$\alpha$ and A are known. The free parameters is n. The data consists of different values of $\phi$ and y.

Is there any way to fit such a function using any standard plotting software? That is can the fit function be defined in this way?

N.B: n is NOT necessarily an integer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about recommending software/detailing the use of software, not about physics.